Faster ways of selecting rows in a Pandas dataframe based upon a string
I'm trying to select specific rows from a Pandas dataframe using a string to match values. As I'm running this repeatedly then I'm looking for the fastest way to do this. I've found that I can hash the string value and subset on this value to speed things up. Is there a better approach with improved performance?
import pandas as pd
import random
from string import ascii_letters
from timeit import default_timer as timer

# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(range(100000000)), columns=["id"])
df['searchtext'] = [''.join(random.choice(ascii_letters) for x in range(3)) for _ in range(len(df))]
df['hash'] = df.searchtext.transform(hash)
print(df)

# Standard text search
start = timer()
df[df.searchtext == 'aaa']
end = timer()
print(f'text search took {end-start} seconds')

# Search using hash
start = timer()
df[df.hash == hash('aaa')]
end = timer()
print(f'text search took {end-start} seconds')

The hash search seems to be about 50-60 times faster.

The hashed comparison is faster since it's numerical.
An even better approach would be to convert the column to Categorical, this way you can keep using the original comparison, it's also saving memory if you have many duplicates:
df['searchtext'] = pd.Categorical(df['searchtext'])

df[df.searchtext == 'aaa']

Timings on 1M rows:
# string comparison
104 ms ± 10.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# hash comparison
2.25 ms ± 263 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# Categorical comparison
1.87 ms ± 259 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

